# PHP MySQL: Search database for string (in array) missing results

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I am creating a feature which searches a database for a string. The PHP shows no errors using a PHP validator and, if the search term doesn't exist, it returns the correct errors. My problem is that, when searching for the term 'abandon hastily' in the column of the database entitled 'collocation' (which is currently the only entry in the database), no results are returned. Though I can see using phpMyAdmin that this entry does definitely exist.

The string is entered by a user into an input field using the following HTML:

```
<form action='http://www.murkyfiles.esy.es/search.php' method='GET'>
  <center>
    <p><label for='search'>Please enter your question as accurately as possible:</label></p>
    <p><input type='search' size='90' name='search'></p>
    <p><input type='submit'  name='submit' value='Find answer'></p>
  </center>
</form>
```

The term entered is searched on the database using the following PHP:

```
<?php
$button = $_GET [ 'submit' ];
$search = $_GET [ 'search' ];
$host = "[HOST URL]";
$username = "[USERNAME]";
$password = "[PASSWORD]";
$database = "[DATABASE]";
$searchlength = strlen($search);

if( !$button )
  echo "You didn't submit a keyword";
else {
  if( strlen( $search ) <= 1 )
    echo "Search term too short";
  else {
    echo "You searched for <b> $search </b> <hr size='1' > </ br > ";

    // Connect to database

    $con = mysqli_connect ( $host, $username, $password );

    if(!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' .PDO::errorInfo());
    }

    mysqli_select_db ( $con, $database );

    $search = str_split($search, $searchlength);

    $construct = " SELECT * FROM 'coll_test' WHERE collocation LIKE '%$search%' ";

    $run = mysqli_query( $con, $construct );

    //Fetch and return search results.

    if ($foundnum == 0)
        echo "Sorry, there are no matching results for <b> $search[0] </b>.
        </ br >
        </ br > 1. Try presenting your Something is wrong in a more academic manner. Guidance can be found on the majority of University websites without need for registration.
        </ br > 2. Try more common words/phrases with similar meaning. This search focuses on colloquialisms - commonly used phrases within a language.
        </ br > 3. Please check your spelling";

    else {
      echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

      while ( $runrows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run) ) {
          $collocation = $runrows ['collocation'];
        echo "<a href='$url'> <b> $title </b> </a> <br> $desc <br> <a href='$url'> $url </a> <p>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked at various similar questions and none of them offer solution.

To clarify, the database table column headers are as follows:

> **collocation** | **left** | **right** | **length** | **google-results** |  **bing-results** | **yahoo-results** | **url-link** | **wiki** | **date**

There is, so far, only one entry in my database:

```
collocation = abandon hastily
left = abandon
right = NULL
length = 2
google-results = 24000000
bing-results = 386000
yahoo-results = 385000
url-link = oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search1?word=abandon
wiki = 0
date = [TIMESTAMP]
```

Comment: So what is `$foundnum` where it is defined?

Comment: Why are you using `str_split`?

Comment: Sorry saty my internet is a bit temperamental. Will try it out now.

I used str_split because I was being told it must be an array, not a string... but I was using two search words 'abandon hostility' and I wanted to find the result which matches the entire string, not just the results which match 'abandon' and 'hostility' separately. Wasn't sure how to do it with explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite rewrite, with notes below:

```
$con = mysqli_connect ( $host, $username, $password, $database );

//$search = str_split($search, $searchlength); ///??? See below
$searchSafe = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z-_ ]/i","",$search); //example only.

$construct = " SELECT COUNT(*) AS found FROM `coll_test` 
WHERE collocation LIKE '%".$searchSafe."%' ";

$run = mysqli_query($con, $construct);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($run);

print $result['found']." number of results found!"; //for example.
```

1) You can include the database reference in the MySQLi connection function.

2) [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) returns an **array** but you are using the result as a string. This is confusing and incorrect, what do you intend to do with this?

- `$_GET['search']` will always be a string type, so you do not need to use it as an array or any array-based messing around with it.

3) Having outside functions manually returning a `number_rows` count can be inaccurate, [instead use `COUNT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939442/best-way-to-count-rows-from-mysql-database) within the `SELECT` statment.

4) You forgot to return the result of your actual query! So above I have inserted a `mysql_fetch_array` result to see the number of results. You also did not define a value for your `$foundnum` variable.

5) You are mixing PDO with MySQLi, these two connection methods are **mutually exclusive**. They do not mix.

6) You are wide open to SQL injection and database compromise you need to use Prepared Statements (as well exampled by [Saty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896094/3536236) ) and use something like `preg_replace` (or another REGEX parser) to remove invalid characters from strings, such as:

```
$searchSafe = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-z-%_ ]/i","",$search); //example only.
```

The above would mean only 0-9 or a-z (case insensitive, *`/i`*) or `-`, `%` or `_` are allowed in the string.

7) table or column names (`'coll_test'`) should not be encased in single quotes, instead they shold be encased in backticks, if at all. In MySQL single quotes are for containing data strings **only**.

Comment: Thanks. This rewrite, along with @Saty 's answer, have resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap off quotes form table and column name instead use backtick and your code is open for sql injection user prepare and bind statement to prevent it

```
$search = $_GET ['search'];// get your value
$like = "%$search%";//
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `collocation`,`left`,`right` FROM `coll_test` WHERE collocation LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $like);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($collocation,$left,$right);
$rows = $stmt->num_rows;// check your query return result of not
if ($rows > 0) {

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {// fetch data from query
       printf ("%s (%s)\n", $collocation,$left,$right);
       // fetch data form result set
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there are no matching results for <b> $search </b>.";
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)` what is $run here  ??

Comment: @Saty I have updated the code (can be viewed at http://www.murkyfiles.esy.es/search.php )but it still returns no result

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET ['search']` ??@DjDaihatsu. Also check data is present in your database or not

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.

['search'] refers to the input of type 'search'  from the form in my html

Comment: Run this query into your phpmyadmin and check what it return `SELECT * FROM coll_test WHERE collocation LIKE '%abandon hostility%'`

Comment: Not sure if you meant to make an incorrect string...

running that returns "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0001 sec )"

and running the same but replacing 'hostility' with 'hastily' returns

Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0002 sec)

with my entry displayed

Comment: Tested with update and now I get


Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home/u598468705/public_html/search.php on line 23
Sorry, there are no matching results for abandon hastily .

Comment: Instead of `*` in query use column name !! check updated answer!! Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php