# What is the Big-O algorithmic time complexity for COUNT(*) on a MySQL table's total rows?

Tags: mysql, big-o

What is the Big-O (O(?)) for counting the number of rows in a MySQL table?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) rows FROM myTable
```

I could not find this information in the documentation, but in this case, I am assuming that there is no `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you're asking if there is some place in a MySQL database that contains an up-to-date row counts for all tables, then the answer is no. Otherwise, the answer is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [MySQL - Complexity of: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257973/mysql-complexity-of-select-count-from-mytable).

For those curious on what "big-O" means, it refers to the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of a computational operation.