# Is count() the most efficient way to count the number of objects?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, count

I need to count the number of objects of a particular model in my database and display the number with a context processor for the user to view on every page.

Right now I'm simply doing `Model.objects.count()`. It works, but as there are now more than 400,000 objects in the db, it has noticeably slowed things down.

I'm running on my development server, so maybe once I push to dedicated servers this won't be a problem, but I'm not sure... I'm worried what will happen once we get into the millions or beyond. Any tips?

Comment: This depends more on the database engine. A `COUNT(*) FROM table` can be as fast as *O(1)* so that means that the number of elements do not matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5258011/67579

Comment: In postgresql count is O(N). Do you really need the exact number of rows for each request?

Comment: @soon Adding reference: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/. It's basically written in the first lines of text. `When you apply the COUNT(*) function to the entire table, PostgreSQL has to scan the whole table sequentially. If you use the COUNT(*) function on a big table, the query will be slow. This is related to the PostgreSQL MVCC implementation.`

Comment: And furthermore... if an exact number is not needed you can do an estimate, see here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

Answer (score 0):

If the estimate you get from `pg_class.reltuples` is good enough, go for it. That would be the simplest solution.

If you need exact numbers, you could do that with a trigger. The following example keeps a count of the table `mytab` in `mytab_count`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytab_count (
   c bigint NOT NULL
);  

-- make sure there cannot be more than one row
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytab_count_singleton
   ON mytab_count ((1));

INSERT INTO mytab_count
   SELECT count(*) FROM mytab;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   CASE TG_OP
      WHEN 'INSERT' THEN
         UPDATE mytab_count SET c = c + 1;
         RETURN NEW;
      WHEN 'DELETE' THEN
         UPDATE mytab_count SET c = c - 1;
         RETURN OLD;
   END CASE;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER count_trig AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON mytab
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE count_trig();
```